# Any Grid suggestions for Breeze?

Tags: breeze

We decided to use Web API, EF + ASP.NET MVC 4 + Knockout + Breeze for our project after a long research.
But we can not find any working grid for Breeze. We want to bind breeze entities to grid and be able to edit data on grid for some scenarios.

We try new grids almost everyday but still no luck,
for example, we tried jqxGrid (from jqWidgets) but it throws an exception while binding data (possibly because of circular references between entities). If we don't use breeze entity and select an anonymous type it works ok.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we decided to go with KoGrid, after some research, we could do all we need. Thank you all for help. You may find our test code below. Have a nice day.

```
    <!--3rd party library scripts -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/q.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.json-2.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/KoGrid.debug.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var GridViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.products = ko.observableArray();
            self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
            self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
            self.totalServerItems = ko.observable(80);
            self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
            self.sortInfo = ko.observable();
            self.filterInfo = ko.observable();
            self.updateItem = function () { };

            var entityModel = window.breeze.entityModel;
            var entityManager = new entityModel.EntityManager('api/Service');
            var metadataStore = entityManager.metadataStore;
            metadataStore.importMetadata($.toJSON(metadata));
            var op = window.breeze.FilterQueryOp;

            this.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, filterInfo, sortInfo) {
                var columnName = "ProductID";
                if (sortInfo != null)
                    columnName = sortInfo.column.field + " " + sortInfo.direction;

                var query = entityModel.EntityQuery.from("Products").orderBy(columnName).skip((page - 1) * pageSize).take(pageSize);
                for (var propertyName in filterInfo) {
                    query = query.where(propertyName, op.StartsWith, filterInfo[propertyName]);
                }

                entityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                    self.products.removeAll();
                    var items = data.results;
                    items.forEach(function (item) {
                        self.products.push(item);
                    });
                });                    
            };

            this.dataChangedTrigger = ko.computed(function () {
                var page = self.currentPage(),
                    pageSize = self.pageSize(),
                    filterInfo = self.filterInfo(),
                    sortInfo = self.sortInfo();

                if (page && pageSize) {
                    self.getPagedDataAsync(pageSize, page, filterInfo, sortInfo);
                }

                return null;
            });
        }

        var model = new GridViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(model);
        model.getPagedDataAsync(10, 1, model.filterInfo(), model.sortInfo());
    });
</script>

<div id="sandBox" class="example" style="height: 600px; width:600px; max-width: 700px;" 
    data-bind="koGrid: { data: products,
                        columnDefs: [{ field: 'ProductName', width: 200 },
                                     { field: 'QuantityPerUnit', width: 200 },
                                     { field: 'UnitPrice', width: 150 }],
                         autogenerateColumns: false,
                         isMultiSelect: false,
                         enablePaging: true,
                         useExternalFiltering: true,
                         useExternalSorting: true,
                         filterInfo: filterInfo,
                         sortInfo: sortInfo,
                         pageSize: pageSize,
                         pageSizes: [10, 20, 50],
                         currentPage: currentPage,
                         totalServerItems: totalServerItems,
                         selectedItem: selectedItem }">
</div>

<!-- Application scripts -->
<script src="~/Scripts/breeze.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/metadata.js"></script>
```

Comment: The version 2.0 of koGrid now has many more features and all the bindings can now be done directly in javascript. I even made a binding handler that automatically converts an existing readonly cell template into an editable one here: https://github.com/ZiadJ/kgEditable/blob/master/kgEditable.js

Comment: But version 2.0 doesn't have per column filters and we really need them. Also we need grouping :) We are a little confused here, we will decide whether grouping or column filters are more important or we will have to seek for another grid.

Comment: I don't really mind because with knockout it's easy to implement my own per column filter using separate inputs but yeah it would be nice to have it out of the box like before. So I suggest you make a request for it on the issues page if its not already there. However check this out: http://ericmbarnard.github.com/KoGrid/#/examples#grouping Grouping is here to stay in v2.0!

Comment: I just checked out the issues page and it looks like the multi column grouping is planned for v2.2: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/issues/17

Comment: We already implemented per column filtering in our ViewModel base with a few lines of code so derived ViewModels can use filtering automatically, but now we have to write lots of code for every View and ViewModel and it doesn't feel right while we could do this with 1.2 version simple and classy.

You're right, we will make a request :)

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for a grid for some time too. I examined jQGrid, koGrid, slickGrid and some more. I am using DataTables with a knockout extension now, which can be found here: 
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4969/knockoutjs/p1

It can be styled with bootstrap and is highly customizable with templates and much more.
You have to do some linking between breeze and DataTables, but it works very well for me.

Comment: Thank you, we will be trying datatables on monday.

Comment: [http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/28544#Comment_28544](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/28544#Comment_28544)
... 
Above link is to thread, this is direct link to the relevant post.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to have an editable grid with KO.

This is a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/wx8cL/

(please don't mind the CSS :D )

Basically, you can have a row template for viewing, and a row template for editing:

```
<script id="inner-row-tmpl" type="text/html">
        <td data-bind="text: par1"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: par2"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: par3"></td>
        <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
</script>

<script id="row-tmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'inner-row-tmpl'}">
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="editable-inner-row-tmpl" type="text/html">
        <td class="editable-row" data-bind="text: par1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: par2"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: par3"/></td>
</script>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the sample. We need a little powerful grid (have sorting, filtering capabilities etc.) so we don't exceed our short deadline. I think we will go with KO grid.

Comment: humm... it looks pretty good. I will leave the link here : https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid